# How to run ant commands from a jar file of the same Java project?

Tags: java, jar, ant

I have a java project with a build.xml file, and multiple ant commands. I can create a jar file of this project, but I want to be able to use the jar to run those other ant commands.

Questions:

1. Is this even possible?
2. Would it be better to create an executable jar file for each of the ant commands I need to run?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. A Jar file is a Zip archive with the `.jar` extension and the file layout for a Java executable. Just unpack the Jar file, and do what you want with the contents.
2. Probably. Either one tool that accepts arguments to change its behaviour, or one per specific task. Use whichever approach makes the most sense for your project.